# Azure separation of environments

Tags: azure

I have a few Windows VMs on Microsoft Azure Cloud, their uses are: dev, test and production.

What would be the best way to separate the VMs to different isolated environments, so that people won't accidentally deploy a dev build on the prod server and things like that? At what entity level (billing, subscriptions, resource group...) should the separation happen?

Demands:
1. Different roles will be created to each environment, so dev people can't upload to test or prod.
2. Each environment should have the ability to define environment variables (for connection strings and passwords).
3. I don't use Visual Studio as my IDE.
4. I must use only one subscription, because I've got a subscription with free budget for a year, and I think that if I'd open another subscription - I'll have to pay.

Comment: Have you thoroughly read the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is

Comment: Hey @PeterBons, I did read the docs but missed that one, as I was searching from the environment point of view, and not from the users' role point of view. Your link did answer my question, so thank you for that. And also thank you for down-voting my question, and giving me a bad feeling for seeking help after searching online for more than 2 hours. I hope that when you'll seek for help people will choose to give you free-loving answers instead of down-voting your legitimate question and leave you with bad taste in your mouth during your use of this great platform...

Comment: I wonder why you think I downvoted you. Because it was not me, probably someone else. So be careful who you blame. And while I was happy to provide you with a helpful links this remark of you leaves me a bad taste as well. If you feel being treated unjust, imagine my feeling now. Have a nice day!

Comment: Well, never said I'm perfect, but I do know to admit my faults... I shouldn't have blamed you without checking first, no matter how closely timed was your comment and the down-vote... I'm sorry man, thanks for your help! Keep spreading the love :)

Comment: :-) Will do ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter Bons referred, the answer is: use a different Resource Group to represent an environment, and give users permissions to it.

link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is

Comment: It is worth noting that an advantage of dev in a separate subscription is that you can get cost savings by marking it as for dev.